# Access 2010 form not displaying query

Tags: field, ms-access-2010

I'm sure this is an easy fix but I can't seem to find it. I just have a form, that will be a subform of another, that needs to display the results of a query.

The query is simple enough, just displays all fields of records that fall between specified dates. The query works great, but when I attach it to the form as its record source it doesn't display the data. I can see the correct amount of record selectors so I know its understanding the query but its as if all fields are hidden!

I have also tried building a query to the forms record source that was simply  Select query.* From query. Oddly I have had this working before but I had to specify every field. What I mean is:

Select title From query
Select type From query
Select date From query
...

And so on for all the fields but this seems foolish, can anyone think of what I may be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit, forgot to mention I also tried the foolish solution that I mentioned above and it didn't work so its definitely some issue that I'm not seeing, some property that's probably not appropriately set**

@sshekhar well its not really code at the moment I'm using Access 2010. I have a form that needs to display a subform that executes this query of displaying records that have a data field that fall between dates specified by  the user. The query works and displays the correct records, but the form that it is attached to only shows the record selectors and all the fields appear to be "hidden." I thought it may be one of the form's properties set incorrectly but I checked on the test form from another database that I used and each have what appears to be identical settings. So I'm at a loss!

Comment: What kind of form? Single, datasheet, continuous? Are you sure the field names match the control sources? Does the query refer to another form?

Comment: Its is a datasheet form. The query does get the start and end date from the parent form.

Comment: Can you post the record soure?

Comment: Record Source: SELECT qryRecordFilter.* FROM qryRecordFilter;

Comment: The Query:  SELECT *
FROM tblEquipment INNER JOIN tblMaintenancePeriod ON tblEquipment.EquipID = tblMaintenancePeriod.EquipID
WHERE (((tblMaintenancePeriod.DownDate) Between ([Forms]![frmRecordEdit]![cmbStartMonth] & " " & [Forms]![frmRecordEdit]![cmbStartDay] & "," & [Forms]![frmRecordEdit]![cmbStartYear]) And ([Forms]![frmRecordEdit]![cmbEndMonth] & " " & [Forms]![frmRecordEdit]![cmbEndDay] & "," & [Forms]![frmRecordEdit]![cmbEndYear])));

Comment: The reason the Where is so big is that I have 3 boxes to select a date so that a user can't enter something unexpected, but they all are combined to make a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out even though I using a query that holds all the fields it will not display the content unless you go to the Add Existing Fields and add all the the fields you want to see. This seems really silly especially when the results in the query but at least its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and discovered that having the property DataEntry set to YES will *only* display new records. From [Microsoft Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/dataentry-property-HA001232728.aspx):

> You can use the DataEntry property to specify whether a bound form
>   opens to allow data entry only. The Data Entry property doesn't
>   determine whether records can be added; it only determines whether
>   existing records are displayed. Read/write Boolean.